# Operations that use only RAM

Tags: xcode, swift

Can you please tell me some example code where we use ignorable amount of CPU and storage but heavy use of RAM? Like, if I run a loop and create objects, this will consume RAM but not CPU or storage. I mean tell me some memory expensive operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift the `Int64` type requires 64 bit of memory. So if you allocate space for 1000000 `Int64` you will reserve memory for 8 MB.

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<Int64>.alloc(1000000)
```

The process should not consume much CPU since you are not initializing that memory, you are just allocating it.

Answer (score 3):

[appzYourLife](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1761687/appzyourlife) gave a good example, but I'd like to give a more conceptual answer.

Memory is slow. Like it's really slow, at least on the time scale that CPUs operate on. There is a concept called the [memory hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_hierarchy), which illustrates the trade off between cost/capacity and speed.

To prevent a fast CPU from wasting its time waiting on slow memory, we came up with [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache), which is a very small amount (it's expensive!) of very fast memory. The CPU never directly interacts with RAM, only the lowest level of CPU cache. Any time the CPU needs data that doesn't fall in the cache, it dispatches the [memory controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_controller) to go fetch the desired data from RAM and put it in cache. The memory controller does this directly, without CPU involvement (so that the CPU can handle another process while wasting on this slow memory I/O).

The memory controller can be smart about how it does its memory fetching however. The [principle of locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) comes into play, which is the trend that CPUs tend to deal mostly with closely related (close in memory) data, such as arrays of data or long series of consecutive instructions. Knowing this, the memory controller can prefetch data from RAM that it predicts (according to various prediction algorithms, a key topic in CPU design) might be needed soon, and makes it available to the CPU before the CPU even knows it will need it. Think of it like a surgeon's assistant, who preempts what tools will be needed, and offers to hand them to the surgeon the moment they're needed, without the surgeon needing to request them, and without making the surgeon wait for the assistant to go get them and come back.

To maximize RAM usage, you'd need to minimize cache usage. This can be done by doing a lot of unexpected jumps between distant locations in memory. Typically, linked structures (such as linked lists) can cause this to happen. If a linked structure is composed of nodes that are scattered all throughout RAM, then there is no way for the memory controller to be able to predict all their locations and prefetch them. Traversing such a structure will cause many "cache misses" (a memory request for which the data isn't cached, and must be fetched from RAM), which are RAM intensive.

Ultimately, the CPU would usually be used heavily too, because it won't sit around waiting for the memory access, but will instead execute the instructions of the other processes running on the system, if there are any.